# EeePC 1005HA keyboard not working after GRUB

Tags: keyboard

I am trying to install any light-weight 32-bit Linux distribution on my Asus EeePc 1005HA. While booting from a USB I am able to use the keyboard in GRUB menu, but once past that the keyboard and touchpad are not working. External keyboard and mouse work fine. After browsing for a while I suspect the laptop is being recognized as a tablet and inputs are disabled, but I'm no expert and cannot confirm that. I've tried, Lubuntu 19, Puppy Linux 8 and 9, anitX 22, MX 23, Porteus 5. It's the same result in every system.

EDIT: After software updates were installed in Linux Lite 3.8 the internal keyboard started working.

Comment: Can you check the BIOS? Maybe you need to switch on the USB Legacy Support.

Comment: USB Keyboard is working properly.

Comment: That's why I told you, try to switch on the USB legacy support.

Answer (score 0):

Checked in BIOS, no USB legacy support line found with current BIOS.

All USB related lines were enabled, and same behaviour described above with Debian 12 fresh install.